# Getting "footprint is not defined" error message when using timelineMonth view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I'm getting the following error message when trying to use the "timelineMonth" default view:

[image]

I'm using fullCalendar 3.9.0 and Scheduler 1.9.3

Here is my implementation:
[image]

Comment: Hi! It would be a lot easier for others to find and help answer your post if you could include the error, versions and implementation as text as well as images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Agreed. Images if code are not helpful, for various reasons.

Comment: Anyway, please can you show the code where you actually include the relevant script files in your page as well, please?